# What do I do when OS X freezes?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, imac, performance

It happened to me twice recently. I was just using my iMac normally, like browsing the web, and it suddenly freezes. I can move the mouse, but I can't click on anything. Keyboard not functioning at all. I couldn't figure out what to do except for pressing the power button and reboot. What else can I do? Is there a way to diagnose and find out what is causing it?

Answer (score 5):

A strategy to try when the freeze is actually happening is holding <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>, then hitting <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd>.

If your keyboard input is still working, this should bring up the force-quit dialog (which can be navigated using the arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd>).  This may allow you to close problematic applications without a hard shutdown using the <kbd>⌽ Power</kbd> button.

Answer (score 1):

Usual troubleshooting steps for similar cases are:

1. **Clean system and user cache** (slightly dangerous procedure if you don't know what you're doing) there is a program called CleanGenius that might help, but it's been severely limited due to the new sandboxing policies introduced with OS 10.7
2. **repair Disk Permissions** (easy, you can do it with Apple's Disk Utility, which is installed by default in the Utilities folder)
3. **Reset PRAM** (easy, you need to start up your computer keeping four keys pressed: command, option, P, R and release them AFTER you heard the startup chime TWICE)

Those steps should solve the problem.

Differential diagnosis would be checking the RAM for a defective bank and checking internet plugins (but in that case, I suppose not all the system would lock up, just the browser) and processes running in the background. But for this kind of diagnosis, I would suggest entrusting your Mac to a specialist.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the dust bunnies out of the video card. After months of making me crazy I think I tracked it down to dust blocking the heat sink channels on my video card. I was blaming my freezed on Flash, but I realize that was working my video card just hard enough it got hot and quit. Haven't had a freeze in days.